# Is this an opinion-based question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

I have some specific questions related to the following technical domain. I'll post a few details, but not the complete question so people without knowledge in this domain can also answer. The question has the potential for a wide-variety of answers and I would like to write the question in a such a way as not to limit what kinds of answers I receive because this technique is one that I have not tried before and I am open to a variety of tips and solutions.

**Programming language**: FileMaker

**Problem doman**: Multiple-language support for DB

**Technical method**: repetition fields

**Requirements**:
...

**Question**: What would the disadvantages be of implementing a solution with this technical method?

Is this question likely to get positive reactions? How could I best format the question contents so it's not too opinion-based?

Could I post a list of specific technical questions and also state that I'm open to any other points that I should consider?

Comment: "too opinion-based" - a combination of "too broad" and "primarily opinion-based" ;)

Comment: Ask a real **specific** question instead of asking for opinions.

Comment: Could I improve it by giving an example of the data I would like to store and asking if this method would allow me to use the multi-language database in multiple markets without requiring any complicated work-arounds?

Comment: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Actually it is question asking for people's experience with specific examples. Is that considered to be an opinion-based question?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes - SO has become narrower and narrower in this regard over the years because "discussion" type questions tended to attract a lot of bad content and generally didn't work well in the eyes of the community here. *Some* types of "whiteboard" questions are on topic on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ but how this one would have to be changed to fit the bill, I don't know and would probably be best asked on their Meta.

Comment: @Pekka웃 such question would be a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see [What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260) Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat that's why I said it would likely have to be changed, and asked about first on their Meta.

Comment: How about questions like these: If I use repetition fields, how could I place multiple fields on a layout without needing to program each separately? If I use repetition fields, how can I set-up the layout such that there is enough space for each field in the repetition without having too much white space?

Comment: @Bobby better would be here's my code for placing repetition fields on a layout. Is there some way to reduce the amount of layout code so that I don't need separate code for each field. Or Here's my repetition field code, it produces too much whitespace. It looks like this and I'd like it to look like this instead.

Comment: @RobertLongson, thanks, that helps a lot. I will see what I can do. Often for FileMaker, though, "coding" means doing a lot of clicking and going through various menus. That makes it difficult to share code. But maybe I can to a test and take some screenshots of the configuration?

Comment: @bobby screenshots are not searchable and therefore don't make useful questions for us. Although they are useful, one must be able to read, understand and answer a question without them. If you can't manage that then your question will be closed.